# How can a Guest can also Download Torrent from TorrentTrade v3

Tags: php

I want to Download torrent file as Guest too from download page.
I am Using TorrentTrade Script which is set to Membersonly MODE, When users are login they can download .torrent file which also assign them a passkey, i want to know what code i should add or modify from download.php file by that a guest can also download .torrent file having a passkey too.

```
<?php
require_once("backend/functions.php");
dbconn();

if ($_GET["passkey"]) {
    $CURUSER = mysqli_fetch_assoc(SQL_Query_exec("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN groups ON users.class=groups.group_id WHERE passkey=".sqlesc($_GET["passkey"])." AND enabled='yes' AND status='confirmed'"));
}

//check permissions
if ($site_config["MEMBERSONLY"]){
    loggedinonly();

    if($CURUSER["can_download"]=="no")
        show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("NO_PERMISSION_TO_DOWNLOAD"), 1);
}

$id = (int)$_GET["id"];

if (!$id)
    show_error_msg(T_("ID_NOT_FOUND"), T_("ID_NOT_FOUND_MSG_DL"), 1);

$res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT filename, banned, external, announce FROM torrents WHERE id =".intval($id));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

$torrent_dir = $site_config["torrent_dir"];

$fn = "$torrent_dir/$id.torrent";

if (!$row)
    show_error_msg(T_("FILE_NOT_FOUND"), T_("ID_NOT_FOUND"),1);
if ($row["banned"] == "yes")
    show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("BANNED_TORRENT"), 1);
if (!is_file($fn))
    show_error_msg(T_("FILE_NOT_FOUND"), T_("FILE_NOT_FILE"), 1);
if (!is_readable($fn))
    show_error_msg(T_("FILE_NOT_FOUND"), T_("FILE_UNREADABLE"), 1);

$name = $row['filename'];
$friendlyurl = str_replace("http://","",$site_config["SITEURL"]);
$friendlyname = str_replace(".torrent","",$name);
$friendlyext = ".torrent";
$name = $friendlyname ."[". $friendlyurl ."]". $friendlyext;

SQL_Query_exec("UPDATE torrents SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = $id");

require_once("backend/BEncode.php");
require_once("backend/BDecode.php");

//if user dont have a passkey generate one, only if tracker is set to members only
if ($site_config["MEMBERSONLY"]){
    if (strlen($CURUSER['passkey']) != 32) {
        $rand = array_sum(explode(" ", microtime()));
        $CURUSER['passkey'] = md5($CURUSER['username'].$rand.$CURUSER['secret'].($rand*mt_rand()));
        SQL_Query_exec("UPDATE users SET passkey='$CURUSER[passkey]' WHERE id=$CURUSER[id]");
    }
}

if ($row["external"]!='yes' && $site_config["MEMBERSONLY"]){// local torrent so add passkey
    $dict = BDecode(file_get_contents($fn));
    $dict['announce'] = sprintf($site_config["PASSKEYURL"], $CURUSER["passkey"]);
    unset($dict['announce-list']);

    $data = BEncode($dict);

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');

    //header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)); 

    header("Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent");

    print $data; 

}else{// external torrent so no passkey needed

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');

    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fn));  

    header("Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent");

    readfile($fn); 
}

mysqli_close($GLOBALS["DBconnector"]);
?>
```

Here is my download.php file Please guide what to do changes to get download file too as Guest too as well as member, member and guest both should get download .torrent file.

Comment: Why aren't you using prepared statements?

Comment: @dharman I didn't understand what is your mean by prepared statement

Comment: You should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).